# Search engine problem while building a website (TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined)

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having a problem making a search engine for this website I'm building. It is about a system that helps you find Scientists all around the world.

I set up two search boxes (`nameSearchQuery` and `instituteSearchQuery`), one for searching through the scientists' name (`Author Name`), and one for the College or University they attended (`Institute Name`).

I get this error when trying to search the Institute Names, but not for the Author Names, could it be because of different types?

I've tried fixing this by changing the order of these If statements, but that is not the problem.

```
if (nameSearchQuery)
  filtered = allScientists.filter((m) =>
    m["Author Name"].toLowerCase().includes(nameSearchQuery.toLowerCase())
  );
  
if (instituteSearchQuery)
  filtered = allScientists.filter((f) =>
    f["Institute Name"]
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(instituteSearchQuery.toLowerCase())
  );
```

Comment: Show the `allScientists` example which doesn't work, now it seems that there is no `'Institute Name'` property, it can be that typo

Comment: Before applying toLowerCase(), must check property exist. filter(m => m["Author Name"] ? m["Author Name"].toLowerCase().includes(nameSearchQuery.toLowerCase() : true)

Answer (score 0):

try this. You need firstly check if property exist in object then you can safely (with no errors) access it. You could also use ESnext syntax `m["Author Name"]?.toLowerCase()?.includes(nameSearchQuery.toLowerCase())`  `f["Institute Name"]?.toLowerCase()?.includes(instituteSearchQuery.toLowerCase()`

```
if (nameSearchQuery) {
    filtered = allScientists.filter( (m) => {
        if ("Author Name" in m) {
            m["Author Name"].toLowerCase().includes(nameSearchQuery.toLowerCase())
        }
    } );
}

if (instituteSearchQuery) {
    filtered = allScientists.filter( (f) => {
        if ("Institute Name" in m) {
            f["Institute Name"]
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(instituteSearchQuery.toLowerCase())
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Before I used to get an error while typing in the `instituteSearchQuery` search box, now I don't. But when I type anything inside the search boxes, even the `nameSearchQuery`, I get no results in the `filtered`.

Comment: some item of `allScientists` might not have `Author Name` or `Institute Name` properties therefore the error happened

Comment: I narrowed down the dataframe to about 200 scientists, instead of 159683, and I checked all of the current scientists to make sure they have those properties, yet the results are the same.